# Creating a ISO-8859-1 string from a HEX-string in Java, shifting bits

Tags: java, encoding, hex, byte-shifting

I am trying to convert a HEX-sequence to a String encoded in either, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8 or UTF-16BE. That is, I have a String looking like: `"0422043504410442"` this represents the characters: `"Test"` in UTF-16BE.

The code I used to convert between the two formats was:

```
private static String hex2String(String hex, String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    char[] hexArray = hex.toCharArray();

    int length = hex.length() / 2;
    byte[] rawData = new byte[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        int high = Character.digit(hexArray[i*2], 16);
        int low = Character.digit(hexArray[i*2+1], 16);
        int value = (high << 4) | low;
        if( value > 127)
                value -= 256;
        rawData[i] = (byte) value;
    }
    return new String(rawData, encoding);
}
```

This seems to work fine for me, but I still have two questions regarding this:

1. Is there any simpler way (preferably without bit-handling) to do this conversion?
2. How am I to interpret the line: `int value = (high << 4) | low;`?

I am familiar with the basics of bit-handling, though not at all with the Java syntax. I believe the first part shift all bits to the left by 4 steps. Though the rest I don't understand and why it would be helpful in this certain situation.

I apologize for any confusion in my question, please let me know if I should clarify anything. 
Thank you.
//Abeansits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there any simpler way (preferably without bit-handling) to do this conversion?**

None I would know of - the only simplification seems to parse the whole byte at once rather than parsing digit by digit (e.g. using `int value = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);`)

```
public static byte[] hexToBytes(final String hex) {
  final byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

**How am I to interpret the line: int value = (high << 4) | low;?**

look at this example for your last two digits (42):

```
int high = 4; // binary 0100
int low = 2; // binary 0010
int value = (high << 4) | low;

int value = (0100 << 4) | 0010; // shift 4 to left
int value = 01000000 | 0010; // bitwise or
int value = 01000010;
int value = 66; // 01000010 == 0x42 == 66
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `<<` and `|` in this case with `*` and `+`, but I don't recommend it.

The expression

```
int value = (high << 4) | low;
```

is equivalent to

```
int value = high * 16 + low;
```

The subtraction of 256 to get a value between -128 and 127 is unnecessary. Simply casting, for example, 128 to a byte will produce the correct result. The lowest 8 bits of the `int` 128 have the same pattern as the `byte` -128: 0x80.

I'd write it simply as:

```
rawData[i] = (byte) ((high << 4) | low);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any simpler way (preferably
>   without bit-handling) to do this
>   conversion?

You can use the [Hex](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class in Apache commons, but internally, it will do the same thing, perhaps with minor differences.

> How am I to interpret the line: `int value = (high << 4) | low;`?

This combines two hex digits, each of which represents 4 bits, into one unsigned 8-bit value stored as an `int`. The next two lines convert this to a signed Java `byte`.